# What is the correct mapping notation for this set-valued function?

Tags: notation

Let $P \subset \mathbb{N}$ be a finite index set. Given $i \in P$, suppose

- $c(i) \subset P$ returns a particular subset of $P$
- and $e(i) \in c(i)$ returns are particular element of that subset.

How are $c$ and $e$ expressed in arrow notation? Since $c$ is a set-valued function, presumably
$$
c : P \to \mathcal{P}(P),
$$
where $\mathcal{P}(P)$ is the [set of all subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of $P$.

For $e$, naturally
$$
e: P \to P
$$
is correct, but, it doesn't convey that $e(i) \in c(i) : i \in P$. So, would
$$
e: P \to c[P],
$$
where $c[P]$ denotes the image of $P$ under $c$, be correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $c\colon P \to \mathcal{P}\left(P\right)$, but we cant write $e\colon P\to c\left(P\right)$. Set $c\left(P\right)$ is subset of $\mathcal P\left(P\right)$ and we don't need that set.

Function $e$ takes index $i$ and returns element of $c\left(i\right)$. As $c\left(i\right)\subseteq P$, it follows that $e\left(i\right)\in P$, so type of function $e$ is $$e\colon P\rightarrow P.$$

Comment: I agree that $e: P \to P$ is correct, but I would like to express that $e(i) \in c(i)$. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: You cant express that information using only arrow notation. You could say that $e=\min \circ c$, where $\min$ is minimum of a set. That equation completely determines function $c$ (including the fact that $e\left(i\right)\in c\left(i\right)$).